# problems with outlook and emails

Tags: email, outlook, html-email

New to coding and i can not for the life of me see why this email is not working in outlook 2010, it's just the top part as well, any advise on how to fix this or

```
<table>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" width="15px">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td width="50">
                    <img alt="" height="99" src="http://www.uploadlibrary.com/first4families/TCM-Test/cell_03.png" width="123" /></td>
                    <td align="right" valign="top" width="585"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table bgcolor="#5BBBB7" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 600px">
                <tr>
                    <td height="340px" width="600px">
                    <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 574px">
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3" style="height: 32px; width: 574px">
                            <img alt="" height="32" height="32px" src="http://www.uploadlibrary.com/first4families/TCM-Test/cell_07.png" width="574" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td rowspan="2" style="height: 279px; width: 13px">
                            <img alt="" height="279" src="http://www.uploadlibrary.com/first4families/TCM-Test/cell_09.png" width="13" /></td>
                            <td align="left" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px" style="display: block; font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000; line-height: 14px; height: 212px;" valign="top" width="218px">
                            </td>
                            <td rowspan="2" style="height: 279px; width: 343px">
                            <img alt="" height="279" src="http://www.uploadlibrary.com/first4families/TCM-Test/cell_11.png" width="343" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="height: 67px; width: 218px">
                            <img alt="" height="67" src="http://www.uploadlibrary.com/first4families/TCM-Test/cell_12.png" style="display: block" width="218" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Outlook accepts height / width CSS, so stick to the HTML attributes instead.

Also- take the px off of your html attributes, that should solve a chunk of it.

Set `display:block` on all your images too, and if I remember correctly Outlook isn't great at `rowspan` - try and separate your tables rather than trying to have rows with different amounts of columns.